# Send GET request from one php file to another php file

Tags: php, openstreetmap

I have a php file that takes JSON data coming from a url. I want some keys and values to be included in my local database and remaining keys and values to be uploaded in the database of OpenStreetMap (OSM).

I want to call the respective php file with the GET parameters from the main php file.

My script looks like this:

```
<?php

$url = "something";

$parts = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($parts);

//echo(sizeof($json));  

$private = array("people_count");

$to_osm = array("Rent","drinking_water","Shop","communication","Energy_source","waste_management","Internet_access","emigrants","number_storey","adboard");

foreach ($json as $object) {

    $get_url = "?id=";

    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {

        if ($key == "osmid") {
            $id = $value;
            $geom = "Polygon";
            $get_url.=$id."&geom=".$geom;
            //print_r($get_url);
        }

        elseif (in_array($key, $to_osm)) {
            $get_url.="&".$key."=".$value;
        }






    }
    print_r("updateOSM.php".$get_url);





}



?>
```

I tried include but that didn't worked. I cannot redirect my page as I am running loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: header('Location: updteOSM.php'.$get_url);

Comment: Remember that [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) in OSM are always lower case, except for names in values.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
header('Location: updateOSM.php'.$get_url);
exit();
```

Comment: Dont forget `exit();` after `header();` function.

Comment: @trzyeM- , Hi , After you hit this statement , You will goto another page immediately braking next execution ,So you dont need exit() Or die()

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird as you said it is not necessary to put exit() or die() but in some sort of conditions they are required. so it is good to keep them.

Comment: @user3510665 `in some sort of conditions they are required` ? Can you please give at least 1 example of it ? See After `header()` NO statement will get executed.So it will be Extra line of code which will NEVER execute.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Check live http headers for firefox.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird in one of my previous project in if statement i wrote header in if block, it was redirected but unwanted errors are appeared after placing exit() statement that worked fine for me. so it will BETTER if keep them.

Comment: @Biplov Bhandari you can try shell scripting for your requremnt

Answer (score 0):

Anyway

```
header('Location: updateOSM.php'.$get_url);
```

Is proper solution , because After you hit this statement , You will goto another page immediately braking next execution ,So you dont need `exit()` Or `die()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
<?php

$url = "something";

$parts = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($parts);

$private = array("people_count");

$to_osm = array("Rent","drinking_water","Shop","communication","Energy_source","waste_management","Internet_access","emigrants","number_storey","adboard");

foreach ($json as $object) {

    $get_url = "?id=";

    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {

        if ($key == "osmid") {
            $id = $value;
            $geom = "Polygon";
            $get_url.=$id."&geom=".$geom;
            //print_r($get_url);
        }

        elseif (in_array($key, $to_osm)) {
            $get_url.="&".$key."=".$value;
        }           

    }

    header('Location: updateOSM.php'.$get_url);

}

exit();
?>
```

The redirected url looks like this:

updateOSM.php?id=*******&geom=Polygon&Rent=no&drinking_water=public_supply&Shop=no&communication=yes&Energy_source=solar&waste_management=septic_tank&Internet_access=yes&emigrants=no&number_storey=7&adboard=yes

The id it shows is the last index of my array $json. And when I checked the changes on the feature in osm.org itself, I see only the last feature being modified and not others.

What I want is updateOSM to take every array element not just the last one to make changes.

Comment: Whether or not I keep exit() only the last index of the array is being modified and not all of them.